# Unable to Download Large File From SharePoint Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm unable to download certain files from SharePoint. I think it's because of size but not sure. I was able to download a 500M file. I'm on Windows 7. I upgraded PS to 5.1 and installed the SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline module. My SharePoint authentication is based on multi-factor authentication.

Ultimately, I'm looking to create an script and automate it that gets a list of files and their attributes and based on some condition download specific ones. Some will be 5Gig+.

At PS Prompt:

```
Connect-PnPOnline –Url  https://server.sharepoint.com/personal/user –UseWebLogin

Get-PnPFile -Url "Documents/5gig_file.csv" -AsFile
```

I was able to download other files. When trying this larger file I get error:

```
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-PnPFile -Url "Documents/5gig_file.csv" -AsFile
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPFile], FormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Files.GetFile
```

Edit - After more searching around I think this may be related to "MemoryStream" limit having to do with Powershell and not anything to do with SharePoint. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4129.

Comment: Just adding a bit of feedback, I looked through all the SP, module, and type docs and couldn't find any remarks on file size limits.  It may be a setting through SP itself.

Comment: Thanks @TheIncorrigible1. I neglected to mention I can download the 5G files from the SharePoint web interface.

Comment: I think they have opened issue for this problem, https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/issues/1797